# Youtube API in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-youtube-api

I've been trying to build a app using Youtube API. I am trying to display youtub's video's in list view but i am getting error in Binary XML file.
This is my Activity.

```
  @TargetApi(13)
  public final class VideoListDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnFullscreenListener {

  /** The duration of the animation sliding up the video in portrait. */
  private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 300;
  /** The padding between the video list and the video in landscape orientation. */
  private static final int LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP = 5;

  /** The request code when calling startActivityForResult to recover from an API service error. */
   private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    private VideoListFragment listFragment;
    private VideoFragment videoFragment;

    private View videoBox;
    private View closeButton;

    private boolean isFullscreen;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.video_list_demo);

    listFragment = (VideoListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
    videoFragment =
            (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

    videoBox = findViewById(R.id.video_box);
    closeButton = findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    layout();

    checkYouTubeApi();
}

    private void checkYouTubeApi() {
    YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason =
            YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(this);
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else if (errorReason != YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS) {
        String errorMessage =
                String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
        // Recreate the activity if user performed a recovery action
        recreate();
    }
}

     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    layout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
    this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;

    layout();
    }

    /**
    * Sets up the layout programatically for the three different states. Portrait, landscape or
    * fullscreen+landscape. This has to be done programmatically because we handle the orientation
    * changes ourselves in order to get fluent fullscreen transitions, so the xml layout resources
    * do not get reloaded.
    */
    private void layout() {
    boolean isPortrait =
            getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    listFragment.getView().setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
    closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (isFullscreen) {
        videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    } else if (isPortrait) {
        setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } else {
        videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
        int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
        setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
        int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4 - dpToPx(LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP);
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
}

    public void onClickClose(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View view) {
    listFragment.getListView().clearChoices();
    listFragment.getListView().requestLayout();
    videoFragment.pause();
    ViewPropertyAnimator animator = videoBox.animate()
            .translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight())
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
    runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

     @TargetApi(16)
     private void runOnAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Runnable runnable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        animator.withEndAction(runnable);
    } else {
        animator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                runnable.run();
            }
        });
    }
    }

   /**
   * A fragment that shows a static list of videos.
   */
   public static final class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
    static {
        List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
        list.add(new VideoEntry("YouTube Collection", "Y_UmWdcTrrc"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Tap", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("Chrome Multitask", "UiLSiqyDf4Y"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("Google Fiber", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("Autocompleter", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Motion", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
        list.add(new VideoEntry("Translate for Animals", "3I24bSteJpw"));
        VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    private PageAdapter adapter;
    private View videoBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity(), VIDEO_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        videoBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_box);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String videoId = VIDEO_LIST.get(position).videoId;

        VideoFragment videoFragment =
                (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
        videoFragment.setVideoId(videoId);

        // The videoBox is INVISIBLE if no video was previously selected, so we need to show it now.
        if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                // Initially translate off the screen so that it can be animated in from below.
                videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
            }
            videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // If the fragment is off the screen, we animate it in.
        if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0) {
              videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        adapter.releaseLoaders();
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
        adapter.setLabelVisibility(visible);
    }

}

    /**
    * Adapter for the video list. Manages a set of YouTubeThumbnailViews, including initializing each
    * of them only once and keeping track of the loader of each one. When the ListFragment gets
    * destroyed it releases all the loaders.
    */
    private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
    private final List<View> entryViews;
    private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

    private boolean labelsVisible;

    public PageAdapter(Context context, List<VideoEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;

        entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

        labelsVisible = true;
    }

    public void releaseLoaders() {
        for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
            loader.release();
        }
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
        labelsVisible = visible;
        for (View view : entryViews) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoEntry getItem(int position) {
        return entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

        // There are three cases here
        if (view == null) {
            // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
            YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
            thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
        } else {
            YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
            if (loader == null) {
                // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
                //    current videoId in the tag.
                thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
            } else {
                // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
                //    on the loader.
                thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
                loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
            }
        }
        TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
        label.setText(entry.text);
        label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        return view;
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(
                YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
            loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
            thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
            String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
            loader.setVideo(videoId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(
                YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, ErrorReason errorReason) {
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
        }
    }

}

public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
implements OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private String videoId;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance() {
        return new VideoFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
        if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
            this.videoId = videoId;
            if (player != null) {
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
        this.player = player;
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
        player.setOnFullscreenListener((VideoListDemoActivity) getActivity());
        if (!restored && videoId != null) {
            player.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        this.player = null;
    }

}

    private static final class VideoEntry {
    private final String text;
    private final String videoId;

    public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.videoId = videoId;
    }
}

    // Utility methods for layouting.

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSizeAndGravity(View view, int width, int height, int gravity) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    params.gravity = gravity;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}

 }
```

And my Video_List_demo.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.tryyyyyy.VideoListDemoActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClickClose"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.tryyyyyy.VideoListDemoActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </merge>
```

And my video_list

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="95dp"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My LogCat is.

```
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): Process:  com.example.tryyyyyy, PID: 3609
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.tryyyyyy/com.example.tryyyyyy.VideoListDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
    07-03 17:01:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3609):     ... 11 more
```

My Manifest is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tryyyyyy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
    android:label="@string/videolist_demo_name"
    android:name=".VideoListDemoActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have decleared different class for DeveloperKey. 
Could anybody help?

Comment: where's defined this Fragment : com.example.tryyyyyy.VideoListDemoActivity ?? , your package is : com.examples.youtubeapidemo so it's outside the main package or it doesn't exist , and it seems that it's an Activity not a Fragment : VideoListDemoActivity !!

Comment: I have update manifest.

Comment: When exactly does the crash occur? Is it when trying to displaying the list or when you click on a list's element?

Comment: At the starting @dextor